# 404 Error in Deployment of MERN App - Cyclic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, deployment, mern

I am trying to deploy a full stack mern app using cyclic however, when trying to access the url which is https://hilarious-teal-binturong.cyclic.app, I get a 404 error. I have added the [environment variables](https://imgur.com/QiHW82v). I have also ran npm run build in the frontend which using vite. I can't seem to really understand why this is happening. The github link is https://github.com/gbopola/product-feedback-app.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change my server.js file to serve my built frontend as static assets.